# How to check the modules installed date?

Tags: 6

How to check which modules was installed on what date?  I am using Drupal 6. I can not find any answer in Google.

Comment: Funnily enough I was wondering this exact same thing for D6 yesterday.  I gave up trying if I'm being honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have that information with default core and contrib module.

You can get the time module upload on your server by checking last modify time of module file.

If you realy want to have module install information, you should create a patch that change the module_enable function on includes/module.inc file.

Comment: Just meant to say what sanglt say. Just look at `{system}` table - information you want is simply not there. Operating Sysetm's `mtime` and `ctime` may reveal upload times, but that's not guaranteed (for performance reasons not all fs store them, and even the ones that can allows them to be changed). In Drupal 7 you have a [hook_modules_enabled()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_modules_enabled/7) to record what you want in future, in 6 I can't see a way other than patch.